# Python - comparing excel files

Tags: python, excel

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx')

if df1.values == df2.values:
    print("Values are same")
else:
    print("Values are not same")
```

I found this code and it shows the output with error
"error: new 1.py:18: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

```
 if df1.values == df2.values:"
```

I need to read a certain column on both workbooks and compare them.
Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use csv-diff library (https://pypi.org/project/csv-diff/)

Install it by using :

```
pip install csv-diff
```

Comment: I'm using **df1.values** which reads all the values, what should I do if I need to read a certain column(column of my choice), please give me some suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If only wants to know if the 2 Excel files are the same:

```
df1.equals(df2)
```

It prints out True or False.